# Cassandra: Query with where clause containing greather- or lesser-than (< and >)

Tags: cassandra, where-clause, cql

I'm using Cassandra 1.1.2  I'm trying to convert a RDBMS application to Cassandra. In my RDBMS application I have following table called table1:

```
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
```

1. Col1: String (primary key)
2. Col2: String (primary key)
3. Col3: Bigint (index)
4. Col4: Bigint

This table counts over 200 million records. Mostly used query is something like:

```
Select * from table where col3 < 100 and col3 > 50;
```

In Cassandra I used following statement to create the table:

```
create table table1 (primary_key varchar, col1 varchar, 
col2 varchar, col3 bigint, col4 bigint, primary key (primary_key));

create index on table1(col3);
```

I changed the primary key to an extra column (I calculate the key inside my application).
After importing a few records I tried to execute following cql:

```
select * from table1 where col3 < 100 and col3 > 50;
```

This result is:

```
Bad Request: No indexed columns present in by-columns clause with Equal operator
```

The Query **select col1,col2,col3,col4 from table1 where col3 = 67** works

Google said there is no way to execute that kind of queries. Is that right? Any advice how to create such a query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cassandra indexes don't actually support sequential access; see http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/ddl/indexes for a good quick explanation of where they are useful. But don't despair; the more classical way of using Cassandra (and many other NoSQL systems) is to denormalize, denormalize, denormalize.

It *may* be a good idea in your case to use the classic bucket-range pattern, which lets you use the recommended RandomPartitioner and keep your rows well distributed around your cluster, while still allowing sequential access to your values. The idea in this case is that you would make a second dynamic columnfamily mapping (bucketed and ordered) `col3` values back to the related `primary_key` values. As an example, if your `col3` values range from 0 to 10^9 and are fairly evenly distributed, you might want to put them in 1000 buckets of range 10^6 each (the best level of granularity will depend on the sort of queries you need, the sort of data you have, query round-trip time, etc). Example schema for cql3:

```
CREATE TABLE indexotron (
    rangestart int,
    col3val int,
    table1key varchar,
    PRIMARY KEY (rangestart, col3val, table1key)
);
```

When inserting into `table1`, you should insert a corresponding row in `indexotron`, with `rangestart = int(col3val / 1000000)`. Then when you need to enumerate all rows in `table1` with col3 > X, you need to query up to 1000 buckets of `indexotron`, but all the `col3val`s within will be sorted. Example query to find all `table1.primary_key` values for which `table1.col3 < 4021`:

```
SELECT * FROM indexotron WHERE rangestart = 0 ORDER BY col3val;
SELECT * FROM indexotron WHERE rangestart = 1000 ORDER BY col3val;
SELECT * FROM indexotron WHERE rangestart = 2000 ORDER BY col3val;
SELECT * FROM indexotron WHERE rangestart = 3000 ORDER BY col3val;
SELECT * FROM indexotron WHERE rangestart = 4000 AND col3val < 4021 ORDER BY col3val;
```

Answer (score 0):

If col3 is always known small values/ranges, you may be able to get away with a simpler table that also maps back to the initial table, ex:

```
 create table table2 (col3val int, table1key varchar,
                      primary key (col3val, table1key));
```

and use

```
 insert into table2 (col3val, table1key) values (55, 'foreign_key');
 insert into table2 (col3val, table1key) values (55, 'foreign_key3');
 select * from table2 where col3val = 51;
 select * from table2 where col3val = 52;
 ...
```

Or

```
 select * from table2 where col3val  in (51, 52, ...);
```

Maybe OK if you don't have too large of ranges.  (you could get the same effect with your secondary index as well, but secondary indexes aren't highly recommended?).  Could theoretically [parallelize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36690811/32453) it "locally on the client side" as well.

It seems the "Cassandra way" is to have some key like "userid" and you use that as the first part of "all your queries" so you may need to rethink your data model, then you can have queries like `select * from table1 where userid='X' and col3val > 3` and it can [work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48755128/32453) (assuming a clustering key on col3val).